# %rename and %inline in swig, error checking

Tags: python, swig

I use SWIG and Numpy. I define a C function called `inplace()` to process data array fast, and I want to make some error checking (if two arrays have the same dimentions).

I use `%rename` and `%inline` in the `.i` file. As I understand, rename should map the function names', so every time someone uses `inplace`, `safe_inplace` is run and the errors are checked.

But it does not work :( . As far I notice, safe_inplace is not executed, python runs directly `inplace` without touching the safe version of the function.

```
# .i

%include "inplace.h"
%rename (inplace) safe_inplace;

%inline %{
    void safe_inplace(int* datain, int in_dx, int in_dy, int in_dz,
                      int* dataout, int out_dx, int out_dy)
    {
        if ((in_dx != out_dx) || (in_dy != out_dy)) { 
            PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError, /*... messgage*/) 
            return;
        } 

        inplace( /* .. pass the arguments to original function*/ );
    }
```

header file:

```
# .h 

void inplace(int* datain, int in_dx, int in_dy, int in_dz, int* dataout, int out_dx, int out_dy);
```

Python:

```
#.py
inplace.inplace(a,b)
```

The original example that I modify can be found [here](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/SWIG_NumPy_examples)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original approach was close, but you probably want to get SWIG not to wrap the original version of the function at all.

I've put together a slightly simpler example illustrating how this could work. Given the header file:

```
void foo();
```

We want to wrap it such that a slightly modified version is called before invoking the real one.

The simplest way to do this would be to *never* actually show SWIG the header file at all for wrapping, only for compiling the wrapper, e.g.:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>
%}

%rename (foo) foo_safe;
%inline %{
  void foo_safe() {
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
    foo(); // Calls the foo() from test.h, as you'd hope
  }
%}
```

If you don't want to drop the `%include` (e.g. there's other things you care about in that header file too) you can do something like:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>
%}

%rename (unsafe_foo) foo;    
%include "test.h"

%rename (foo) foo_safe;    
%inline %{
  void foo_safe() {
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
    foo();
  }
%}
```

To expose the real implementation of `foo` as `unsafe_foo`.

Or you could use `%ignore` if there's no reason for Python users to be able to call `unsafe_ignore` ever:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>
%}

%rename (foo) foo_safe;    
%inline %{
  void foo_safe() {
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
    foo();
  }
%}

%ignore foo;    
%include "test.h"
```

Finally it looks like your goal is actually just to run some code prior to the call of the real C function. If that's the case there's a few ways you can do that too, for example you can add python code before the real function call is made with `pythonprepend`:

```
%feature("pythonprepend") foo() %{
   print "hello world"
   # check args and raise possibly 
%}
```

Or lastly you could use the `%exception` functionality too, something like (untested):

```
%exception inplace {
   // Check args and possibly throw
   $action
}
```

`$action` will be substituted with the real call automatically.

Comment: thanks! Question here: why you include twice `test.h` in the example with `unsafe_foo`? Doesn;t it meant that `foo` will be available both as `foo` and `unsafe_foo` (overhead)?

Comment: @JakubM. nope, it's not going to be there twice, one's a `#include`, inside a `%{` `%}` pair and the other is a `%include`. The latter tells SWIG to bring the contents of the file into the .i file (exactly like `#include` in C or C++). The former tells SWIG that the generated wrapper filer (test_wrap.cxx in this example) needs to include that exact code verbatim, that is to say that test_wrap.cxx will contain that exact `#include`, but otherwise the contents of the `%{ %}` has no impact on SWIG itself.